# Appending <link> to <head> using jQuery does not work

Tags: jquery, append, favicon

I have put all my favicon  tags and reference to my stylesheet (my header contents html are in another file) in a separate text file that I can load on all my pages. This is what I have done:

favicon.txt:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon/favicon-196x196.png" sizes="196x196">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon/favicon-160x160.png" sizes="160x160">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
```

index.html:

```
<script id="favicon"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#favicon").load("favicon.txt");
    });
</script>
```

Now the problem is, this script loads the stylesheet part successfully, but fails with the favicon part. The same thing works perfectly well when I use the following:

```
$("head").append('<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">');
```

Comment: you are loading favicon part inside `script` tag which accept only css / javascript and not html part. put this html part in seperate file and append it to head.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: (didnt test it)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "favicon.txt",
}).done(function(data) {
    $("head").append($(data));
});
```

Comment: Did IE say something? wich version?